# Extracting an array of string from a paragraph based on style using Microsoft.Office.Interop

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I have a word file and each paragraph in the word file has text of two styles(for example - font size 16 followed by font size 12). If I only had 1 font size, I could do something like the below code

```
if(wordDoc.Paragraphs[i].Range.Font.Size == 16.0f)
   string text = wordDoc.Paragraphs[i].Range.Text;
```

But in my case, I need to extract content for each font size as a separate string.
Is this possible using Interop?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you need to read from a paragraph.
If all you care about is capturing words formatted differently throughout the document, you might think about using  `Document.Words` to retrieve a collection of words in the document. Each word is a [Range Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

You can use the `Font.Size` property for each Word while iterating through the collection to filter content according to font-size.

Let me know if that helps. Cheers!

Comment: No, that's not what I want. I need to be read each paragraph and extract the set of words formatted differently in each. For example, I know what information I am going to get in paragraph 4 of my document and I know the text that is Font Size 16.0f in paragraph 4 is "information X" and Font Size 12.0f in paragraph 4 is "information Y". I need to extract information X in a string and Information Y in another string.